# Reusing memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm having trouble utilising and understanding the free() function in C.

I tried writing up this example to keep reusing a pointer but I don't understand why error occurs:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct box
{
    char message[20];
}box;


box *newBox()
{
    box *inBox;
    inBox = (box *) malloc(sizeof(box));

    return inBox;
}


int main()
{
    box *temp = NULL;


    temp = newBox();
    strcpy(temp->message,  "Hello");
    printf("%s\n", temp->message);

    free(temp);

    strcpy(temp->message,  "World");
    printf("%s\n", temp->message);

    free(temp);

    strcpy(temp->message,  "People");
    printf("%s\n", temp->message);

    return 0;   

}
```

The output is:

```
Hello
World
memory(531,0x7fff77e9e300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe8ba404a90: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Is there a workaround to fix it?

Comment: The rule is simple: for each pointer you have obtained via `malloc` you need to do one `free` of that pointer and once you have done the `free` the pointer cannot be used anymore.

Comment: after 'temp' is passed to free(), it is nolonger available for use in the program.   in C, do  not cast the returned value from malloc, as it is a void * so can be assigned to any other pointer.   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you have two `free(temp)`s here:

```
temp = newBox();
strcpy(temp->message,  "Hello");
printf("%s\n", temp->message);

free(temp); /* ? */

strcpy(temp->message,  "World");
printf("%s\n", temp->message);

free(temp); /* ? */

strcpy(temp->message,  "People");
printf("%s\n", temp->message);
```

That code should be

```
temp = newBox();
strcpy(temp->message,  "Hello");
printf("%s\n", temp->message);

strcpy(temp->message,  "World");
printf("%s\n", temp->message);

strcpy(temp->message,  "People");
printf("%s\n", temp->message);

free(temp); /* Free the allocated memory after use */
```

Once you `free` the memory, You must not use it. So `free` the memory at the end.

---

*Side note*: The cast here:

```
inBox = (box *) malloc(sizeof(box));
```

is not required and [here is why](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: oh, i thought you had to free the pointer every time you need to point it to a new object.

Comment: @Cool Guy: +1 for saying that remove the cast. but there should be no problem because OP included <stdlib.h>

Comment: @PravasiMeet Right. But it is generally frowned upon for the other reasons mentioned in the link. But it doesn't really matter as OP already has included `stdlib.h`. Thanks for telling!

Comment: @Pyrons [Keep this in mind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219306/reusing-memory-in-c/32219352#comment52321961_32219306)

Answer (score 3):

```
free(temp);
```

Once you do this then the memory allocated by `malloc()`(in this case) is freed.

So the allocated memory is gone and can't be used again, you have to allocate memory again if you want.

Else `free()` the memory only after the required operations are performed on the allocated memory.

Comment: also it invokes UB because same memory being freed more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have free'd the memory that you got through malloc, it no longer belongs to you, and using it is Undefined Behaviour.

You must have exactly one free per malloc, and you must free a pointer before using it in a new malloc - but this does not make much sense unless you a doing tests or what to alloc a different memory size (and in that last use case, you'd better use `realloc`)

Assuming you have good reasons to malloc/free multiple times (this code does **not** exhibit such a requirement), you could do:

```
int main()
{
    box *temp = NULL;


    temp = newBox();
    strcpy(temp->message,  "Hello");
    printf("%s\n", temp->message);

    free(temp);

    temp = newBox();
    strcpy(temp->message,  "World");
    printf("%s\n", temp->message);

    free(temp);

    temp = newBox();
    strcpy(temp->message,  "People");
    printf("%s\n", temp->message);
    free(temp);

    return 0;   

}
```

And please do not cast malloc result in C! It should be:

```
box *newBox()
{
    box *inBox;
    inBox = malloc(sizeof(box));

    return inBox;
}
```